# Concatenar múltiples JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, javascript-objeto, concatenación

Tengo varios JSON objects con diferente estructura y necesitaba concatenarlos para mostrar uno solo, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
 function concatJSON(){
  const user = { "id": 1 , "name": "Travis" , "age": 15};
  const userAccount = { "email": "example@gmail.com" , "password": "123456"};
  const userDogs = [ 
          {    
            "id": 100 ,
            "dogName": "Fluffy"
          }, 
          {    
            "id": 101 ,
            "dogName": "Marggot"
          }
    ];
    
  const jsons = {
    user,
    userAccount,
    userDogs
  };
    
  return JSON.stringify(jsons);

 }
 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = concatJSON();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

El resultado que devuelve es el siguiente:

```
{
"user":{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Travis",
   "age":15
},
"userAccount":{
   "email":"example@gmail.com",
   "password":"123456"
},
"userDogs":[
  {"id":100,"dogName":"Fluffy"},
  {"id":101,"dogName":"Marggot"}
 ]
}
```

Pero el resultado que buscaba era este:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"Travis",
 "age":15
 "email":"example@gmail.com",
 "password":"123456",    
 "userDogs":[
   {"id":100,"dogName":"Fluffy"},
   {"id":101,"dogName":"Marggot"}
  ]
}
```

Al indagar por la web me topé con esta solución:

```
const jsons = {
    "id" : user.id,
    "name": user.name,
    "age": user.age,
    "email": userAccount.email,
    "password": userAccount.password,
    userdogs
}
```

En este ejemplo solo son 3 JSON, pero en mi proyecto debo juntar varios (15 aprox.), incluyendo JSON objects y JSON Arrays.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna otra forma de poder concatenarlos o mezclarlos sin tener que armar un nuevo JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes "unir objetos" con [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign)

```js
function concatJSON(){
  const user = { "id": 1 , "name": "Travis" , "age": 15};
  const userAccount = { "email": "example@gmail.com" , "password": "123456"};
  const userDogs = [ 
          {    
            "id": 100 ,
            "dogName": "Fluffy"
          }, 
          {    
            "id": 101 ,
            "dogName": "Marggot"
          }
    ];
    
  const merge = Object.assign({},user,userAccount);
  merge.userDogs=userDogs;

  return JSON.stringify(merge,null,'  ');

 }
 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<pre>${concatJSON()}</pre>`;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente puedes utilizar el spread operador “...” para hacer estoy sin tener que utilizar object.assign

```
  const jsons = {
   ...user,
   ...userAccount,
   userDogs
};
```

userDogs no lo tiene ya que por el ejemplo dado decesitas ese key en el objeto